# How to abort the ajax request and redirect in the ajax callback of form element

Tags: forms, ajax

I want to redirect users in the AJAX callback, but nothing I tried works.

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 8):

If you've got [ctools](https://drupal.org/project/ctools) installed (nearly all Drupal sites do), you can make use of [`ctools_ajax_command_redirect()`](https://drupal.org/project/ctools) in your AJAX callback, e.g.

```
ctools_include('ajax');
$commands[] = ctools_ajax_command_redirect('path/to/redirect');
return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
```